# java: concurrent iteration over an immutable Iterable

Tags: java, concurrency, iterator, iterable

I have an immutable `Iterable<X>` with a large number of elements. (it happens to be a `List<>` but never mind that.)

What I would like to do is start a few parallel / asynchronous tasks to iterate over the `Iterable<>` *with the same iterator*, and **I'm wondering what interface I should use**.

Here's a sample implementation with the to-be-determined interface `QuasiIteratorInterface`:

```
public void process(Iterable<X> iterable)
{
   QuasiIteratorInterface<X> qit = ParallelIteratorWrapper.iterate(iterable);
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PARALLEL_COUNT; ++i)
   {
      SomeWorkerClass worker = new SomeWorkerClass(qit);
      worker.start();
   }
}

class ParallelIteratorWrapper<T> implements QuasiIteratorInterface<T>
{
   final private Iterator<T> iterator;
   final private Object lock = new Object();
   private ParallelIteratorWrapper(Iterator<T> iterator) { 
      this.iterator = iterator;
   }
   static public <T> ParallelIteratorWrapper<T> iterate(Iterable<T> iterable)
   {
      return new ParallelIteratorWrapper(iterable.iterator());
   }
   private T getNextItem()
   {
      synchronized(lock)
      {
         if (this.iterator.hasNext())
            return this.iterator.next();
         else
            return null;
      }
   }
   /* QuasiIteratorInterface methods here */
}
```

Here's my problem:

- it doesn't make sense to use `Iterator` directly, since hasNext() and next() have a synchronization problem, where hasNext() is useless if someone else calls next() before you do.
- I'd love to use [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), but the only method I need is `poll()`
- I'd love to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue to hold my large number of elements... except I may have to iterate through the elements more than once, so I can't use that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: In the scenario where you want to make a second pass across the data, does the order of iteration need to be the same as the first pass?

Comment: Aside from the course locking and the fact that `null` is a valid entry for many List implementations, what is the problem/question?

Comment: @ChrisH: yes, the order should always be the same.

Comment: @Tim: are you saying I should just use `Iterator` then?

Comment: @Jason S, no because `Iterator` implementations are not guaranteed to be thread safe and from what I have seen the implementation in `AbstractList` is definitely not thread safe. I am simply asking, what is the question?

Comment: @Tim: Oh. The question is what interface is best to use, to decouple the problem of *obtaining* items in the iterable from the problem of *using* those items. As far as `Iterator` goes, it's an interface, and I can implement `Iterator` with proper synchronization within my implementation -- if it's worth using as an interface for this purpose.

Comment: ... e.g. I could define `ConcurrentIterator extends Iterator` with identical methods but constrained semantics (remove() always throws an exception, and hasNext() and next() are threadsafe individually but not threadsafe between calls, so you'd have to expect that next() might throw NoSuchElementException even if you just called hasNext())

Comment: Do you need the same iterator to the underlying collection to be shared between threads? Because you could simply allow each thread to get its own iterator. That will be thread safe.

Comment: @Karthik: yes, because each element must be iterated over exactly once, so I can't do what you suggest.

Comment: @Jason does each thread need to hit every element? Or does it simply mater that some thread touches every element?

Comment: @Karthik: Each element will be used by exactly one worker. (I use "worker" rather than thread, because there may be more than one worker per thread, for various reasons) Each worker will use a subset of the total number of elements. Imagine a box of tissues and 5 people with bad colds. The tissues get used up one by one, by whichever person gets to them next.

Comment: @Jason what you're describing is a work queue. So I would simply implement the queue interface. You can return null or throw unsupported operation exceptions on the methods you don't need and implement only the poll method.

Comment: consider posting an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own `Producer` interface with the `poll()` method or equivalent (Guava's [`Supplier`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Supplier.html) for instance). The implementation options are many but if you have an immutable random access list then you can simply maintain a thread-safe monotonic counter (AtomicInteger for instance) and call list.get(int) eg:

```
class ListSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {
  private final AtomicInteger next = new AtomicInteger();
  private final List<T> elements; // ctor injected

  …
  public <T> get() {
    // real impl more complicated due to bounds checks
    // and what to do when exhausted
    return elements.get(next.getAndIncrement());
  }
}
```

That is thread-safe, but you'd probably want to either return an Option style thing or null when exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Have one dispatcher thread that iterates over Iterable and dispatches elements to multiple worker threads that perform the work on the elements. You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to automate this.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to couple the work-scheduling mechanism (which is complicated and has certain constraints, for reasons outside the scope of this question) with the mechanism that controls sharing access to elements.